# Accessing an image while writing it to file system on iOS

Tags: ios, image, filesystems, file-exists

My app is loading bunch of images from network and saves them to local file system (FS) in app sandboxed environment. When I save image to FS I do it using `GCD` like that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
});
```

And that works just fine. However when I try to get/load this image from FS at the same time (another process needs the same image) I have a problem checking if image exists on FS and if it's readable:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:path]) {
    //step 1 - image exists and I can load it from FS
    UIImage *existingImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]];
    if (existingImage == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Loaded image is nil!");
    }
}
else {
    //step 2 - image does not exist in local FS and needs to be loaded from network
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I get into the step 1 (file obviously exists and is readable) but loaded "existingImage" is nil.

How could that happened?
Is it possible that image is in the middle of write process?
Is there any other way of checking if image write is completed 100% and is ready for use?

Comment: Save it to a subdirectory and move it to cache once completely downloaded? You'll still have problems if another download of the same file is triggered while the first is in progress though.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I totally understand that but what it bothers me is that I get into step 1 even when image is not finished saving 100%. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Just as I said, save the file elsewhere and move it to the directory once it's completely downloaded. Your check won't pick the file up since it's stored elsewhere until it's done, and a move is atomic, so you won't pick up an incomplete file.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This should work. Thanks!